# Modifying blank entries to Null

Tags: python, csv, psycopg2

I'm trying to loop over items in a csv and for anything in the dataset that is blank, set it to "None" or "Null". I am using the modules csv and psycopg2, both already imported.

The overall goal here is to read any items that are blank in the csv and set them to Null. I'm using 
`item = "None"` just to check if the items are found. From there I think I can set it to None.

Sample Data:

`name, age, breed_name, species_name, shelter_name, adopted
Titchy, 12, mixed, cat, BCSPCA, 1
Ginger, 1, labradoodle, dog,,1`

Sample Code:

```
import psycopg2
import csv
for new_pet in dictReader:
    for item in new_pet:
        item = item.capitalize()
        if item is '':
            print item # Used to check/debugging
            item = "None"
```

I can't figure out where I am going wrong here. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: switch the last two lines.

Answer (score 0):

When you update the item inside the for loop it will have no effect on the list it came from. You are not modifying the list but the local "copy" of one item.
You can replace the whole inner for loop with a list comprehension:

```
import csv
for new_pet in dictReader:
    new_pet = [value.capitalize() if value else None for value in new_pet]
    print new_pet
```

This will take all items in new_pet, and run `value.capitalize() if value else None` on them.
That means: If `value` evaluates to `False` (empty strings do), return the value capitalized, if not, return `None`.

Remember to do your data processing per line inside the outer for loop.